# Data integrity across multiple services

Tags: architecture, microservices

I am trying to explore the patterns around data integrity when applying multiple services with access to the same storage.

Let's say I have Service1, which runs in 3 instances.

Whenever an instance of Service1 persists some data to the underlying storage, I would like to enforce that data is not somehow corrupted based on another instance writing to the same location in the storage.

With an RDBMS I can use a locking mechanism on the table but if I use NoSql, how do I go about it ?

Comment: In parallel contexts, never share storage. Have a database engine that can handle it for you. Or implement a CQRS or consensus algorithm where your services request global state changes, and then have to wait to see if the request succeeded.

Comment: This question doesn't seem specific for microservices; the issue exists for any application. I also don't see how it matters how many instances of the services are running; a single service will (practically) always be able to execute multiple requests concurrently anyway, so a single instance deployment has the same issue. If you feel either of these aspects are important, can you please edit the question to explain why?